# How to get uid in bionic libc?

Tags: android, libc, uid, bionic

I am trying to get the uid of the process calling dns files in bionic libc. I know using current->cred->uid.val is used to get the uid in android/linux kernel, but how to get the uid in bionic libc. I don't think the same will work. Can you please suggest me a way to get uid in bionic libc and what headers to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The header is `<unistd.h>`, the functions are `getuid`, `geteuid`, `getresuid` and so on, depending on which kind of UID you need.